# LocalTime to UTC keeping DST

Tags: c#, date, datetime, utc, dst

I have a datagrid that is sorted using a DateTime column that comes from a UTC value converted to local time. the problem is with DST as there is 1 hour in the year that will be repeated (from Nov 6, 2:00:00 AM goes back to 1:00:00 AM). i already implement a way to compare the column using a class that inheriths from IComparable and manually compares dates converting them again using ToUniversalTime() but it returns wrong values. to explain better let me show an example:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("UTC Date", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Columns.Add("Local Date", typeof(DateTime));            
        table.Columns.Add("UTC From Local", typeof(DateTime));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        DateTime aux;

        DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
        aux = new DateTime(2016, 11, 06, 06, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        newRow["UTC Date"] = aux;
        newRow["Local Date"] = aux.ToLocalTime();
        newRow["UTC From Local"] = Convert.ToDateTime(newRow["Local Date"]).ToUniversalTime(); table.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

The values displayed will be:

UTC Date: 11/06/2016 6:30 AM

Local Date: 11/06/2016 1:30 AM

UTC From Local: 11/06/2016 7:30 AM

As you can see the column "UTC From Local" is wrong or at least i would expect 6:30 (considering DST) and not 7:30 (without DST).

Any help?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep in mind the [DateTimeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datacolumn.datetimemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of DataColumn. If you create a new `DataColumn` it is set to **Unspecified**. But in your use case you want **Utc** and **Local**

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("UTC Date", typeof(DateTime)).DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Utc;
table.Columns.Add("Local Date", typeof(DateTime)).DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Local;
table.Columns.Add("UTC From Local", typeof(DateTime)).DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Utc;

var newRow = table.NewRow();
var aux = new DateTime(2016, 11, 06, 06, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
newRow["UTC Date"] = aux;
newRow["Local Date"] = aux.ToLocalTime();
newRow["UTC From Local"] = Convert.ToDateTime(newRow["Local Date"]).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked, let me try to implement this solution to the real app as the one i post was just as an example. so by Reading your solution i can assume that using `ToLocalTime()` does not lose the DST information, the problem was when creating the DataTable that i did not specify the `DateTimeMode`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to get the GTM offset and add it to your "UTC From Local":

```
aux = new DateTime(2016, 11, 06, 06, 30, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
newRow["UTC Date"] = aux;
newRow["Local Date"] = aux.ToLocalTime();
TimeSpan UtcOffset = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(aux);
newRow["UTC From Local"] = Convert.ToDateTime(newRow["Local Date"].Add(UtcOffset)).ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: I don't understand. You call `GetUtcOffset` on UTC? What do you expect?

Comment: I guess calling `GetUtcOffset` on UTC will get 0, anyways also getting that from a date in DST got the same offset tan a date out DST. i believe the only difference is calling `IsDaylightSavingTime()`